# React native. How to execute an action every time we arrive on a view?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm looking to initiate an action everytime a user arrives on a specific view. How can I do that?

None of **componentDidMount** or **componentWillMount** work and if I insert the action inside the **render** method it goes into an infinite loop.

Here is the action I'm trying to call every time a user arrives on the Conversations.js view:

```
this.props.conversationFetch()
```

Comment: Can you please specify your interaction with this page? Can I open the same page twice (e.g. via drawer menu?). Also, what are the contents of your prop conversationFetch?

Comment: You need to add your function inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: @PirShukarullahShah Doesnt work when the view is already mounted. Let's say someone open the app then leaves it. When he opens it again and go on the view if he's not already there then the function isnt called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a combination of `componentDidMount` and the [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) api.

Using the AppState api, you can be notified when the app state changes, so listen to this from your component and run `conversationFetch()` when the state becomes active. That will solve the question from your comment about a user getting to the view by unlocking their phone etc.